# Cannot start React.js app in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webstorm

I am getting this series of error messages when I attempt to start React app in WebStorm.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/JavaScript/React/helloworld/node_modules/acorn-jsx/node_modules/acorn/package.json.1943983600'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: What operating system, and filesystem?

Comment: I am using MacOS

Comment: Can you provide more information on how Webstorm is configured to run your app and what your directory structure looks like?

Comment: I'm guessing here since there is not a lot of info but did you run an npm install before trying to run react?

Comment: Yeah, npm is installed and updated.

Comment: Try to verify the issue is Webstorm related first by running npm install and npm start (or whatever your start script is) using terminal. To me, the issue looks npm related.. see if yarn works or try removing package-lock.json files.